# Google App Engine Updating schema in DB model

Tags: python, google-app-engine, schema

I'm adding new  attribute to an existing data store model. I need to update an existing schema with data to the new schema. I have checked google's doc on [updating schema](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/update_schema?csw=1) and it uses ndb model.

I have a DB model like this:

```
class oldModel(db.Model):
     name = db.StringProperty(default = "")
     author = db.StringProperty(default = "")
     created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
```

My new new schema is:

```
class oldModel(db.Model):
     name = db.StringProperty(default = "")
     author = db.StringProperty(default = "")
     created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
     # new field
     category = db.IntegerProperty(default = 0)
```

How do you do it? (One thing I think of is to include the new schema with a different name and manually populate the data from old one to new schema and drop the old one)

Answer (score 2):

It is really easy to add a property.  Just add it to your model.  For any entities that existed before, they will have the default value.  If your previously existing entities need to have a different value for the new property, then you will have to iterate over them and set the new property to the desired value.

Comment: I'm just adding a new property to the entity. Will my old schema data be populated with default values when I add this model? Or Old model simply exists without this property?